# What do ">>" and "<<" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I have a piece of Javascript code I'm trying to understand

```
// read big-endian (network byte order) 32-bit float
readFloat32 = function(data, offset) {
    var b1 = data.charCodeAt(offset) & 0xFF,
        b2 = data.charCodeAt(offset+1) & 0xFF,
        b3 = data.charCodeAt(offset+2) & 0xFF,
        b4 = data.charCodeAt(offset+3) & 0xFF;
    var sign = 1 - (2*(b1 >> 7));       //<--- here it is and 2 lines below
    var exp = (((b1 << 1) & 0xff) | (b2 >> 7)) - 127;
    var sig = ((b2 & 0x7f) << 16) | (b3 << 8) | b4;
    if (sig == 0 && exp == -127)
      return 0.0;
    return sign * (1 + sig * Math.pow(2, -23)) * Math.pow(2, exp);
}
```

what does ">>" mean? Is it a special type of boolean (like '<' or '>')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are the [**shift right** (with sign)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftRightwithSign.htm) and [**shift left**](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftLeft.htm) operators.

Essentially, these operators are **used to manipulate values at BIT-level**.
They are typically used along with the the `&` (bitwise AND) and `|` (bitwise OR) operators and in association with `masks` values such as the `0x7F` and similar immediate values found the question's snippet.
  The snippet in question uses these operators to "parse" the three components of a 32 bits float value (sign, exponent and fraction).

For example, in the question's snippet:
`1 - (2*(b1 >> 7))`   produces the *integer* value 1 or -1 depending if the bit 7  (the 8th bit from the right) in the b1 variable is zero or one respectively.
This idiom can be explained as follow.

- at the start, b1, expressed as bits is    `0000000000000000abcdefgh`
  note how all the bits on the left are zeros,  this comes from the
  `b1 = data.charCodeAt(offset) & 0xFF`  assignement a few lines above, which essentially zero-ed all the bits in b1 except for the rightmot 8 bits  (0xFF mask).
  a, b, c... thru h represent unknown boolean values either 0 or 1.
  We are interested in testing the value of a.
- `b1 >> 7` shifts this value to the right by 7 bits, leaving
  b1 as `00000000000000000000000a`  which, read as an integer will have value 1 or 0
- this 1 or 0 *integer* value is then multiplied by 2
  it is then either 2 or 0, respectively.
- this value is then substracted from 1, leaving either -1 or 1.

Although useful to illustrate the way the bit-operators work, the above idiom could be replaced by something which tests the bit 7 more directly and assigns the sign variable more explicitly.  Furthermore this approach does not require the initial masking of the leftmost bits in b1:

```
var sign
if (b1 & 0x80)   // test bit 7  (0x80 is  [00000000]10000000)
  sign = -1;
else
  sign = 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

These are bit operators. Have a look at this link: [Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators)

Answer (score 4):

You can read about the operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators

They are bit shifts and also occur in languages other than JS.

Example:  5 >> 1 = 2

binary: 0101 shifting one position = 0010

Answer (score 2):

It is an [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Answer (score 1):

[Right](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftRightwithSign.htm) and [Left](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/ShiftLeft.htm) and shift operators.

Answer (score 1):

shift a by b bits to the left (padding with zeros)

```
a << b
```

shift a by b bits to the right (copying the sign bit)

```
a >> b
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm

> 11.7   Bitwise Shift Operators
>
> ShiftExpression :
>      AdditiveExpression
>       ShiftExpression  << AdditiveExpression
>       ShiftExpression  >> AdditiveExpression
>       ShiftExpression  >>> AdditiveExpression
>
> 11.7.1   The Left Shift Operator ( << )
>   Performs a bitwise left shift operation on the left operand by the amount specified by the right operand. 
>   The production ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression << AdditiveExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> ```
> Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
> Let rnum be ToUint32(rval).
> Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.
> Return the result of left shifting lnum by shiftCount bits. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.
> ```
>
> 11.7.2   The Signed Right Shift Operator ( >> )
>   Performs a sign-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left operand by the amount specified by the right operand.
>
> The production ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression >> AdditiveExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> ```
> Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
> Let rnum be ToUint32(rval).
> Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.
> Return the result of performing a sign-extending right shift of lnum by shiftCount bits. The most significant bit is propagated. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.
> ```

Comment: Not that these convert the numbers into Int32 -- while nearly everything else in javascript works on 64-bit doubles.

Answer (score 0):

shift left and shift right operators. If you have a number it will shift its bits to left or right.

Answer (score 0):

It's the bitshifting operator. See [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/arithmet.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

They are bitshift operators. Numbers in the computer are represented in binary. Shifting left is equivalent to multiplying by 2 and shifting right is equivalent to dividing by 2.

For example, the number 8 is `1000` in binary. Shift left `<<` by 3 would yield `1000000` which is 64. Shift right by 2 would yield `10` which is 2.