# What do the operators ">>" (double arrow) and "|" (single pipe) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this in some JS code:

```
        index = [
            ascii[0] >> 2,
            ((ascii[0] & 3) << 4) | ascii[1] >> 4,
            ((ascii[1] & 15) << 2) | ascii[2] >> 6,
            ascii[2] & 63
        ];
```

I'd quite like to know what a lot of this means. Specifically ">>", a single pipe "|" and the "&" symbol on the last line?

Much appreciated!

Comment: (-1) Search for "JavaScript operators"... -1 because this is readily available information *and* is already far-too-commonly found on StackOverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/single-pipe-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997909/what-do-and-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`x >> y` means to shift the bits of `x` by `y` places to the right (`<<` to the left).

`x | y` means to compare the bits of `x` and `y`, putting a `1` in each bit if either `x` or `y` has a `1` in that position.

`x & y` is the same as `|`, except that the result is `1` if BOTH `x` and `y` have a `1`.

Examples:

```
#left-shifting 1 by 4 bits yields 16
1 << 4 = b00001 << 4 = b10000 = 16

#right-shifting 72 by 3 bits yields 9
72 >> 3 = b1001000 >> 3 = b1001 = 9

#OR-ing 
8 | 2 = b1000 | b0010 = b1010 = 10

#AND-ing
6 & 3 = b110 & b011 = b010 = 2
```

For more information, [search Google for "bitwise operators"](http://google.com/search?q=bitwise+operators).

Answer (score 8):

`>>` is a right bitwise shift. It takes the bits and shifts them right *n* places<sup>1</sup>. For example, let's examine `35 >> 2`:

```
35 = 100011 shift two places
     001000 = 8
```

And indeed, `35 >> 2 == 8`.

---

`|` is a bitwise OR. It takes each bit in each operand and ORs them together. You can envision it as a sort of binary addition, but you don't carry when both top and bottom are `1`. For example, here's `5 | 3`:

```
5 = 101
3 = 011
| -----
    111 = 7
```

And indeed, `5 | 3 == 7`.

---

Finally, `&` is a bitwise AND. It takes each bit in each operand, except instead of giving 1 if either one bit OR the other is one, it gives 1 if one bit AND the other are both one. For example, here's `5 & 3`:

```
5 = 101
3 = 011
& -----
    001 = 1
```

Try it out; `5 & 3 == 1`.

---

Some other ones you might want to be aware of are `<<`, which is a left bitwise shift, and `^`, which is an XOR (0 when both bits are the same, 1 if they're different).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually, it's n modulo 32. `1 >> 32` is `1`. Not sure why.</sub>

Comment: This should be the excepted answer! great explanation

Answer (score 4):

The `>>` and `<<` operators are a bitwise shift. For example,

```
11 =      00001011
11 << 3 = 01011000 = 88
```

It is worth noting that `m << n = m * 2^n` and `m >> n = m / 2^n`. This is sometimes used to do very efficient multiplication/division by powers of 2.

The `&` and `|` are bitwise and and or respectively.

```
11 =      00001011
28 =      00011100
11 & 28 = 00001000 = 8

11 =      00001011
28 =      00011100
11 | 28 = 00011111 = 31
```

While I'm at it, I should mention the `^` operator, which is not used for power, but for bitwise exclusive-or.

```
11 =      00001011
28 =      00011100
11 ^ 28 = 00010111 = 23
```

Answer (score 2):

- & (Bitwise AND)
- | (Bitwise OR)
- << (Left shift)
- >> (Sign-propagating right shift)

Examples (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

Bitwise and:

```
     9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
    14 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001110 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
14 & 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001000 (base 2) = 8 (base 10)
```

Left shift (9 << 2 shifts bits of 9 in binary, 2 bits to the left):

```
     9 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
                  --------------------------------
9 << 2 (base 10): 00000000000000000000000000100100 (base 2) = 36 (base 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bitwise operators to me:

http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html

Edit: that ascii array was a dead give away... LOL